# Access the estimated var in kernlab::gausspr function in R

Tags: r, kernlab

I am looking at the R function `gausspr` from the `kernlab` package for Gaussian process regression.  The process is defined by the hyperparameters of the kernel function and by the noise in the data.  I see in the documentation that I can specify

> var: the initial noise variance, (only for regression) (default : 0.001)

but I do not see how to access the *estimated* value after the regression has run.  For  instance, consider I have some observed points, and want to predict y values at the locations given by `X`:

```
obs <- data.frame(x = c(-4, -3, -1,  0,  2),
                  y = c(-2,  0,  1,  2, -1))
X <- seq(-5,5,len=50)
```

I can do so with `kernlab::gausspr` as such:

```
gp <- gausspr(obs$x, obs$y, kernel="rbfdot", scaled=FALSE, var=.09)
Ef <- predict(gp, X)
```

I can get the estimated value of the kernel hyperparameter:

```
gp@kernelf@kpar
```

But I don't see how I can return the estimated value of the noise parameter, `var`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be overlooking something, but I don't think that the initial noise variance `var` is "fit" to anything; I don't think it is a parameter (although I agree that using the word "initial" makes you think otherwise).

The noise variance is just added to the diagonal of the correlation matrix of the training points, as described on [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/gaussian_process.html) about some other software. Looking through the function definition, it looks like this is exactly what it is doing in `kernlab` as well:

```
# The only relevant line where 'var' is used
alpha(ret) <- solve(K + diag(rep(var, length = m))) %*% y
```

If you wanted to get the error (or any measure of fit) by the noise variance, you could do something like:

```
error.fun<-function(x) error(gausspr(obs$x, obs$y, kernel="rbfdot", scaled=FALSE, var=x))
noises<-seq(0.1,1,by=0.1)
y<-sapply(noises,error.fun)
plot(noises,y,type='l')
```

The built-in cross-validation does not "fit" `var` in any way, from what I can tell. The only relevant line in the cross validation is here:

```
cret <- gausspr(x[cind, ], y[cind], type = type(ret), 
                scaled = FALSE, kernel = kernel, var = var, 
                tol = tol, cross = 0, fit = FALSE)
```

And you can see that `var` is just put in with no changes.

Comment: Yes, I have been wondering about that.  In principle one would estimate this, as it does the length scale, either in cross-validation method or by likelihood (as described here: http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf, see, for instance, figure 5.9)

Comment: Yes, you could certainly examine the fit under different values of `var`. This function does not do that for you.

Comment: Yeah, I just want(ed) to be sure.  I see that the only mention of `var` in that file, but it has a cross-validation method built in, it does estimate the other kernel parameter (length scale), and it calls subroutines not in that file.  If it'll do cross-validation and estimate the length scale, can I be sure it's not estimating var through a subroutine?

Comment: I updated my answer explaining how `var` remains constant over all folds of the cross-validation.